# Установка ключевого поля в datagrid c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Код должен считывать данные из экселя, выводить их в элементы datagrid, и обеспечивать возможность его форматирования прямо из датагрид-ов и последующего сохранения.

```
private void ReadExcel(string path)
{
    string sConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
        "Data Source=" + path + ";" +
        "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
    OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(sConnectionString);
    objConn.Open();
    OleDbCommand objCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [grls2$]", objConn);
    dataClass.objAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    dataClass.objAdapter1.SelectCommand = objCmdSelect;
    dataClass.bulder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dataClass.objAdapter1);
    DataSet objDataset1 = new DataSet();
    dataClass.objAdapter1.Fill(objDataset1, "XLData");
    DataView table = objDataset1.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    dataClass.dt = table.ToTable(); 
    objConn.Close();
}
```

Здесь считывается эксель, все работает как должно.

```
private void upDateData(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    DataColumn[] colums= new DataColumn[1];
    colums[0] = dataClass.dt.Columns["key"];
    dataClass.dt.PrimaryKey = colums;
    dataClass.objAdapter1.UpdateCommand = dataClass.bulder.GetUpdateCommand();
    dataClass.objAdapter1.InsertCommand = dataClass.bulder.GetInsertCommand();
    dataClass.objAdapter1.DeleteCommand = dataClass.bulder.GetDeleteCommand();
    dataClass.objAdapter1.Update(dataClass.dt);
}
```

А здесь уже начинаются проблемы. Эта функция назначена на событие ввода значения в ячейку датагрида, чтобы обновить и записать данные. Однако при ее выполнении выскакивает ошибка типа:

> "System.InvalidOperationException"
>
> Дополнительные сведения: Динамическое создание SQL для UpdateCommand не поддерживается для SelectCommand, не возвращающей никаких сведений о столбце ключей.

Я так понимаю из-за того, что ключевое поле неверно указано. Как её исправить?